# Scala Parser Combinator lexer handling for unterminated string

Tags: scala, parsing, lexical-analysis, parser-combinators

I am wondering how to handle unterminated strings in a lexer/scanner written using the [Scala Parser Combinator library](https://github.com/scala/scala-parser-combinators). The example in class [`scala.util.parsing.combinator.lexical.StdLexical`](https://javadoc.io/static/org.scala-lang.modules/scala-parser-combinators_2.13/2.0.0/scala/util/parsing/combinator/lexical/StdLexical.html) doesn't seem to work.

The main token parser is:

```
def token: Parser[Token] =
  ( identChar ~ rep( identChar | digit )              ^^ { case first ~ rest => processIdent(first :: rest mkString "") }
  | digit ~ rep( digit )                              ^^ { case first ~ rest => NumericLit(first :: rest mkString "") }
  | '\'' ~ rep( chrExcept('\'', '\n', EofCh) ) ~ '\'' ^^ { case '\'' ~ chars ~ '\'' => StringLit(chars mkString "") }
  | '\"' ~ rep( chrExcept('\"', '\n', EofCh) ) ~ '\"' ^^ { case '\"' ~ chars ~ '\"' => StringLit(chars mkString "") }
  | EofCh                                             ^^^ EOF
  | '\'' ~> failure("unclosed string literal")
  | '\"' ~> failure("unclosed string literal")
  | delim
  | failure("illegal character")
  )
```

Setting up a simple test lexer:

```
object Lexer extends App {
    def lex(input: String) = {
        val lexer = new StdLexical
        var scanner: Reader[lexer.Token] = new lexer.Scanner(input)
        while (!scanner.atEnd) {
            println(scanner.first)
            scanner = scanner.rest
        }
    }
}
```

Now, calling that with legal input works, here recognising an identifier and a string literal:

```
> lex(""" hello "world" """)
identifier hello
"world"
```

Passing an illegal character also works as expected:

```
> lex(""" hello € "world" """)
identifier hello
ErrorToken(illegal character)
"world"
```

However, the rule for an unterminated double qouted string does not seem to work and the lexer produces an `ErrorToken(end of input)` instead of the expected `ErrorToken(unclosed string literal)`:

```
> lex(""" hello € "unterminated """)
identifier hello
ErrorToken(illegal character)
ErrorToken(end of input)
```

I guessed the problem was that the rules for unterminated strings use the `failure` parser that allows backtracking but that should have sent us to the last `failure("illegal character")` and btw inserting a cut or alternatively using `err` instead of `failure` doesn't fix the issue.

Any ideas what is wrong with this example?

Comment: you've reported this at https://github.com/scala/scala-parser-combinators/issues/397, I see

Comment: @SethTisue Yes, and I think I have a fix ready. Will issue a PR soon.

Comment: @SethTisue I understand how my fix works. I also understand that the current token rules for unclosed string literals only match the leading quote (which I think is incorrect). However, I do not understand why the rule does not produce the correct error token but jumps to “illegal character”. I thought it was because of backtracking, but then a cut or using `err` should have helped. If you understand, please enlighten me.